# Какие глаголы сочетаются со словом "желание"?

Tags: глаголы, лексическая-сочетаемость, существительные

Какие глаголы сочетаются со словом "желание"?
(Речь идет о воспитательной задаче — что-то вроде "привить" желание не сдаваться.)

Answer (score 3):

"Привить желание" - довольно распространённое выражение, но не самое убедительное, поскольку в буквальном смысле "*привить*" можно только *чужое* и *извне*. Представить себе "привитие (чужого) желания" можно только в форме "делай как я, и тебе это тоже когда-нибудь понравится" (совсем странно "привитие" выглядело бы в форме наставлений, вроде "а ну, давай, хоти!"). Лучше говорить о "**пробуждении**" желания (или интереса), тогда желание точно будет своё  - оно как бы до поры до времени дремлет внутри воспитуемого и при соответствующей постановке учебного процесса может проявиться, стать осознанным. Соответственно, лучше подходит глагол "**пробудить**".

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Выражение "привить желание" встречается в Нацкорпусе:

*Цель проекта — «заставить людей задуматься, насколько они грамотны, и **привить желание** эту грамотность повышать». [Лиза Новикова. Дина Рубина: «Паспортный принцип лишает Россию большого наследства» // Известия, 2013.03.11]*

Этот пример показывает, что "привитие" совершается как бы против воли участников, сначала их надо "заставить", потом уж они привыкнут и сами захотят.

В "Словаре сочетаемости" под редакцией П. Н. ДЕНИСОВА и В. В. МОРКОВКИНА находим: **вызывать желание, будить желание, возбудить желание.**

Замечательно звучит также предложенное Alex_ander **пробудить желание**.

Однако само сочетание "желание не сдаваться" не кажется мне удачным. Тут скорее нужно говорить о воле, а не о желании. А желание обычно связано не с отрицанием какого-либо действия, а с его утверждением, например, *желание остаться*, а не *желание не уходить*.